# Не могу разобраться с импортом интерфейса

Tags: php, composer

Лично для меня какая-то мистика - класс не видит интерфейс. При запуске Lg выдает:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Phone\Baige' not found in
```

Сама структура проекта следующая:

```
Phone
   src
      Baige.php - interface
      Lg.php
   index.php
   composer.json
```

class Lg

```
namespace Phone;

//use Phone\Baige;

class Lg implements Baige
{
    private $name = 'Lg';

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function showBage()
    {
        return 'Hello I am interface Baige';
    }

}

$obj = new Lg();
echo $obj->getName();
```

Baige

```
namespace Phone;


interface Baige
{
    public function showBage();

}
```

composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Phone\\": "src/"

    }
```

composer dumpautoload сделал - ошибок нет

Comment: Зачем писать `use Phone\Baige;` если вы и так в неймспейсе `Phone`?

Answer (score 2):

Не подключен автозагрузчик. В php классы сами по-себе не подключаются нужно вручную. Если используется composer то должна быть папка vendor в ней autoload.php его необходимо подключить (в Lg.php). 
Пример: include **DIR** . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

Comment: Я думаю что в `index.php` надо подключить автозагрузчик.

Comment: Спасибо разобрался. В index подключил -все работакт